# classifying of naïve Bayes classifiers is to choose a $y_k$ to maximize the multiplying (joint probability), is my understanding correct?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, naive-bayes

this [CMU Machine Learning Course](https://youtu.be/tpmdcJYnAyQ?t=2528) says (naïve Bayes classifiers)

> classifying is just a matter of multiplying together those selected parameter estimates that happen to match the values of my new example that I'm trying to classify.

it seems that this expression is kind of misleading.

classifying is argmax rather than just multiplying.

classifying is to choose a $y_k$ to maximize the multiplying.

in other words, only $y_k$ is variable, others are fixed in the phase of classifying, is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in saying that the classification is not finished when we multiply the conditional probabilities. I guess, the professor is saying "it is just a matter of multiplying ..." because the computationally harder part to do is the multiplication. He just omits mentioning the obvious argmax operation, which is comparably much simple. In several scenarios, instead of multiplying probabilities, we see log-likelihoods being added together because it's much more numerically stable, especially when number of features is large.